# Is it legal to draw an NFA with fewer nodes than what I normally see?

Tags: automata, finite-automata, regular-expressions

Is it Ok to express an NFA accepting 1*0 like the one above? All examples in books are represented like the bottom one. I'd like to know is that only a convention or it must have two extra nodes?

[image: Two NFA representations]

Comment: Both NFAs are fine. The bottom one has a lot of redundancy.

Comment: They are fine. The bottom NFA is obtained by a systematic method converting regular expressions to NFAs. So the extra states are not a convention, they are the outcome of a strict, perhaps not optimal, method that yields NFAs. That method is not always efficient in number of states but it has its pros and cons. E.g. it is easy to define formally and prove correct.

Comment: @pedim:This link:(http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/48839/nfa-diagram-for-a) might be a possible solution for your question or you can even check out the chat discussion here:(http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31093/discussion-of-nfa-diagram-for-a).

Comment: Legal in what jurisdiction?

Comment: The bottom NFA contains too much redundancies. Even for method described in https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html, the $ε$-transition from the leftmost state to the next rightmost state should not exist.

Comment: @JingguoYao Does it make the automaton *wrong*?

Comment: @Raphael. No. I think that the bottom NFA is still correct.

Comment: @JingguoYao Then you shouldn't confuse the OP. Ever correct NFA is "legal".

Comment: @Raphael. I am not saying that the bottom NFA is not "legal". I am saying that it contains too much redundancies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a convention. You must know that a regular expression denotes one regular language and this language can be generated by an infinite number of differeny automatona (in this case we are talking about NFA).

Why are you always encountering the second automaton in the books? This is probably because the second automaton is obtained from the regular expression $1^*0$ using a well known method called [Thompson's construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thompson's_construction).

Which of the two automata is better? There isn't just one answer. The first NFA looks simpler but maybe you will have more work when you try to formally prove its correctness. In the other hand the second automaton looks more complex but it was obtained by a proven method so we are sure that it is correct.

Comment: Actually, I think it's easier to prove that the first automaton is correct but +1 for writing pretty much the answer that I would have written.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I guess Renato assumes that you'd recycle correctness of Thompson's construction for a correctness proof, which is definitely easier and faster than any direct proof.

Comment: @Raphael that is the idea! There is not need to reinvent the wheel.